# Profiling memory in an AS3 project

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an AS3 project and while using Mr. Doob's profiler I see that memory usage keeps rising with every second. How can I find out where the leak is coming from? I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve Flash Builder Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it keep going up and up, or does it ever drop?

If you're using FlashDevelop (free), there's a profiler panel that you can set to turn on when you test your SWF. That panel has 3 tabs: Memory, Live Objects Count, and Objects. You can use the Live Objects Count to get an idea of what's currently alive. If you see one type of object continuously going up and never going down, then you've a leak.

Comment: also check out the flash preload profiler from jp auclair: http://jpauclair.net/flashpreloadprofiler/ - it gives you a good visual indication of what's going on, and is pretty easy to use in your project

Comment: I had pretty bad experiences with flash preload profiler and I don't really trust that it provides accurate data. Do you know of any other solution for Mac OS X?

Comment: Also, I noticed it just goes up, didn't stop.

Comment: I agree with @wvxvw; pretty much all of the profilers that you'll find use the basic events/apis made available in flash. You can take a look at the flash.samples package if you want to turn your hand at your own: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sampler/package-detail.html

Comment: I also wrote a class a while back to try and help find memory leaks: http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3 - Basically you mark the objects that you want to track, then call the `gcAndCheck()` method when you're ready to run the gc and see if your objects are collected. If they're still there, then you've a problem

Comment: @wvxvw, I'm not saying I don't trust flash.sampler, just not the flash preload profiler. It's really way off each time I use it. divillysausages, thanks for the link, interesting article.

Answer (score 1):

I don't konw Mr Doob's profiler, but if you try [FlashDevelop's](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) you may be able to have the number of class instances at a moment and monitor their creation. In my opinion a good profiler should include this fonctionnality.

Comment: Is there any solution for Mac OS X?

Comment: I don't own a Mac, but FD may run with VirtualBox, VMWare or Parallel (but I guess you must have installed windows on them).  http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Features